# npm run dev error code ELIFECYCLE. Can't seem to figure out the problem

Tags: node.js, npm

I am not experienced with nodeJS, but I am trying to make some test apps with Plaid, and this error has been showing whenever I run npm run dev.

```
PS D:\Projects\mern-plaid> npm run dev

> mern-auth@1.0.0 dev D:\Projects\mern-plaid
> concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"

[1] 
[1] > mern-auth@1.0.0 client D:\Projects\mern-plaid
[1] > npm start --prefix client
[1] 
[0] 
[0] > mern-auth@1.0.0 server D:\Projects\mern-plaid
[0] > nodemon server.js
[0] 
[0] 'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[0] operable program or batch file.
[0] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[0] npm ERR! errno 1
[0] npm ERR! mern-auth@1.0.0 server: `nodemon server.js`
[0] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[0] npm ERR! 
[0] npm ERR! Failed at the mern-auth@1.0.0 server script.
[0] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[0] 
[0] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[0] npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-08T23_03_35_217Z-debug.log
[0] npm run server exited with code 1
[1] 
[1] > client@0.1.0 start D:\Projects\mern-plaid\client
[1] > react-scripts start
[1] 
[1] 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[1] operable program or batch file.
[1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! errno 1
[1] npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[1] npm ERR!
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
[1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[1]
[1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[1] npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-08T23_03_36_680Z-debug.log
[1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! errno 1
[1] npm ERR! mern-auth@1.0.0 client: `npm start --prefix client`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[1] npm ERR!
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the mern-auth@1.0.0 client script.
[1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[1]
[1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[1] npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-08T23_03_36_727Z-debug.log
[1] npm run client exited with code 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mern-auth@1.0.0 dev: `concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mern-auth@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-08T23_03_36_877Z-debug.log
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Not being able to see what it looks like in a test environment is really difficult

Comment: Try running `npm install -g nodemon` and `npm install react-scripts` in the context of the directory then try again

Comment: To find the _real_ issue in these errors, always look at what was output immediately _before_ the `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE` lines.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, you have to update your node package to last

```
npm install latest-version
```